# What should be the correct "objpoints" for calibrateCamera and stereoCalibrate?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have a stereo camera and I need to do intrinsic and extrinisic calibrations. Although the reprojection error seems fine (<0.1pixel), the extrinsics is odd. The translation between the left and right cameras are too small.

I followed this [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html) for intrinsics of both cameras then used stereoCalibrate for extrinsics.

```
# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(8,6,0)
objp = np.zeros((9*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9,0:7].T.reshape(-1,2)
objpoints2 = []
imgpoints2 = []

# Load images
images = glob.glob('*.tiff')
for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findCirclesGrid(img, (9,7), flags=cv2.CALIB_CB_SYMMETRIC_GRID, blobDetector=detector)
    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret:
        objpoints2.append(objp)
        imgpoints2.append(corners)
        # Draw and display the corners
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (9,7), corners, ret)
        cv2.imshow('img', img)
        cv2.waitKey(50)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
matrix2, distort2 = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints2, imgpoints2, (640,480), None, None)
```

Then I do stereo calibration:

```
R, T = cv2.stereoCalibrate(objpoints2, imgpoints1, imgpoints2, matrix1, distort1, matrix2, distort2, (640,480))
```

My question is what the correct value for objp should be? I used the value from the tutorial, but does it mean my patterns are 1 mm appart?

```
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9,0:7].T.reshape(-1,2)
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

For intrinsic calibration, it doesn't matter if I don't provide the correct distance between the corners.

However, for extrinsics (stereo) calibration, I must provide the correct values otherwise the scale will be wrong and the translation will be small.

Alternatively, I need to multiply the actual pattern distance to the final translation vector for correct scale.